# how to store registration value in to database?

Tags: django, python-2.7

i am trying to store registration value in to database but i am getting error.

the code for this is as below.

views.py

```
def car_vw(request):


    plate = request.POST.get("plate_id", ' ')
    brand = request.POST.get("brand_id", ' ')
    model = request.POST.get("model_id", ' ')
    price = request.POST.get("price_id", ' ')
    condition = request.POST.getlist("select_id[]", ' ')



    queryset1 = car(plate_no=plate, brand=brand, model=model,  daily_price=price, Condition=condition,)

    queryset1.save()
    data = {
        'queryset1': queryset1,

    }

    return render(request, 'car_registration.html', data)
```

Models.py

```
class car(models.Model):

car_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=400, primary_key=True)
plate_no = models.IntegerField(max_length=400)
brand = models.CharField(max_length=400)
model = models.CharField(max_length=400)
Condition = models.CharField(max_length=400)
daily_price = models.IntegerField()
def __str__(self):
    return ' '.join([
        self. ordering,

    ])
```

.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
   <link href="{{ static }}css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <form action="/car/" id="form_id" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}


 <h3>car Registration</h3>
 plate no:<input type="text" id="plate_id" name="plate_id">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 Brand:<input type="text" id="brand_id" name="brand_id"><br>
 Model:<input type="text" name="model_id">
 Daily Price:<input type="text" id="price_id">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 Condition:<select name="select_id[]"><option value="Good">Good</option>
                                <option value="middle">Middle</option>
                                <option value="bad">BMW</option></select>

 <br>
 <input type="submit" id="sub_id">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="cancel_id" VALUE="Cancel">

 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Error:

```
 invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
 error on:        
 queryset1.save()
```

So for solve this problem what can i do so i can easily store the registration values to databese?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a string:

```
  plate = request.POST.get("plate_id", ' ')
```

Convert it to an integer before saving it. Your DB expects an integer.